# Matching the first element of a list with other first elements in the list

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to solve the question given in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=XCeDBWI4sa4
My list contains sub-lists that constitute each digit of a number of the type strings.
Example: I turned my list of strings
`['58','12','50','17']`  into four sub-lists like so  `[['5','8'],['1','2'],['5','0'],['1','7']]`  because I want to compare the first digit of each number and if the first digits are equal, I increment the variable "pair" which is currently 0. `pair=0`
Since 58 and 50 have the same first digit, they constitute a pair, same goes for 12 and 17. Also, a pair can only be made if both the numbers are at either even position or odd position. 58 and 50 are at even indices, hence they satisfy the condition. also, at most two pairs can be made for the same first digit. So 51,52, 53 would constitute only 2 pairs instead of three. How do I check this? A simple solution will be appreciated.
`list_1=[['5','8'],['1','2'],['5','0'],['1','7']]`
and `test_list= ['58','12','50','17']`

```
for i in range(0,len(test_list)):
    for j in range(1,len(test_list)):
        if (list_1[i][0] == list_1[j][0] and (i,j%2==0 or i,j%2==1)):
            pair =pair+1
print (pair)
```

That is what I came up with but I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: you want a dict for that

Comment: what would you like to count if there's a digit with three occurrences? e.g. 51, 52, 53?

Comment: @Roy2012 At most two pairs can be made for the same first digit. So 51,52, 53 would constitute only 2 pairs instead of three.

Comment: @SafiyaHamid *"At most two pairs can be made for the same first digit"* this is confusing. You're trying to say that if we have `51, 52, 53, 54, 55` it would still make only 2 pairs?

Comment: i,j%2==0 is probably not what you want.  That always returns True because tuples are truthy.  Run `(i,j%2==0 or i,j%2==1)`, it will give you a tuple (0,Boolean,Boolean).  The comma is acting as a separator for a tuple

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurrences for each first digit.  Sum up the totals minus the total number of unique types (to account for more than one).
Iterates over even and odd separately:

Uncomment `#return sum(min(c,2) for x in c) - len(c)` if you want it to never count more than 2 for digit duplicates.  eg: [51,52,53,54,56,57,58,59,50,...] will still return 4, no matter how many more 5X you add.  (`min(c,2)` guarantees the value will never exceed 2)

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['58','12','50','17','50','18']


def dupes(a):
    c = Counter(a).values()  # count instances of each element in a, get list of counts
    #return sum(min(c,2) for x in c) - len(c)  # maximum value of 2 for counts
    return sum(c) - len(c)   # sum up all the counts, subtract unique elements (you want the counts starting from 0)

even = dupes(a[x][0] for x in range(0, len(a), 2)) 
# a[x][0]: first digit of even a elements
# range(0, len(a), 2): range of numbers from 0 to length of a, skip by 2 (evens)
# call dupes([list of first digit of even elements])
odd =  dupes(a[x][0] for x in range(1, len(a), 2))
# same for odd
print(even+odd)
```

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz In OP, "51,52,53" counts as 2 pairs.  That would be if he wanted 51,52,53,54 to count as 2.

Comment: Note: if you want a one liner comprehension, you could use enumerate and i%2 and `Counter().update(x)`, but there isn't really any benefit in code elegance nor performance

Comment: I have trouble understanding the code. Could you add comments please?

Comment: comments added, is there a particular part you don't get?

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort though!

Comment: what environment are you running it on and what errors?  Works here: https://repl.it/repls/CarefreePastelOptimization

Answer (score 1):

```
pair = 0
val_list = ['58','12','50','17', '57', '65', '51']
first_digit, visited_item_list = list(), list()

for item in val_list:
    curr = int(item[0])
    first_digit.append(curr)

for item in first_digit:
    if item not in visited_item_list:
        occurences = first_digit.count(item)
        if occurences % 2 == 0:
            pair = pair + occurences // 2
            visited_item_list.append(item)
        
print(pair)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but doesn't satisfy the condition that a pair can only be made if both the numbers are at either even or odd indices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple solution:

```
import collections

l= [['5','8'],['1','2'],['5','0'],['1','7']]

c = collections.Counter([i[0] for i in l])
# Counter counts the occurrences of items in a list (or other 
# collection). After the previous line, c is
# Counter({'5': 2, '1': 2})

sum([c-1 for c in c.values()])
```

The output, in this case, is 2.

Comment: Can you let me know how the line ```sum([c-1 for c in c.values() if c > 0])``` works?

Comment: This works but isn't really following the conditions that are to be met.